# How can i use session variables for a SQL Query for my website?

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

Hello i have a a session value of the user id of the person that has just logged in and i am trying to use that value so that i can display the information from a database of that user and put them in a table.

Query:

`<sql:query var="result" sql= "SELECT * FROM Customer WHere...... "/>`

how can i make it so a session.getAttribute can be entered on the Where part of the query ?
i am using jsp and mysql.

The rest of the code takes the result variable and then puts it in a table on the customer page.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your userId is in the session with the key 'userId' then like the below:

```
<sql:query var="result" sql= "SELECT * FROM Customer where id = ?">
   <sql:param value="${userId}" />
</sql:query>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html